# how to select several links in search page with chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

When i have obtained a result page with many hits in chrome browser, I will need to drag all those links to a instant messenger chat box, such as Skype or windows messenger, so I can send all the links to others. However I can not select all the links and drag them altogether,but only drag them one by one to the chat box instead.
I have tried to use the Ctrl, alt, shift combos, but won't work, can anyone help?

Comment: Is a chrome extension suitable? Try [Copy Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-links/kcpoommnneaebpfgaoejklgemonkmjpc)

Comment: @nixda am i supposed to open it by clicking on your link?It doesnt' work now...

Comment: @nixda i have installed the ext, however, how to use it to copy multiple url within the result page, pls note, not all the url on that page, but selectively copy some?